# Confirmation please : Hold back people

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/joe-biden-welfare-plan-won-103050793.html), there is a line,

> When I was elected governor in 2010, my biggest responsibility was to lead South Carolina out of the Great Recession. I knew that the most vulnerable families needed more than welfare checks — they needed the dignity of a job and a future. So we launched a “Welfare-to-Work” program that matched individuals with jobs that fit their talents. Ultimately, we empowered more than 20,000 South Carolinians to find jobs and flourish.

> Joe Biden and Democrats in Congress could learn a thing or two from South Carolina. Instead of “Welfare-to-Work,” today’s Democrats are all welfare, no work. **This approach will only hold back the people they claim to be helping** and won’t help people thrive long-term.

Does this phrasal verb "hold back" here fall into [**this dictionary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holdback)'s definition,

> 1 b: to keep from advancing to the next stage, grade, or level

Thank you.

Comment: What else do you think it could mean?

Comment: @ColleenV Please read the title. "Confirmation please". Thank you.

Comment: Questions that have a yes or no answer are not on-topic here. You could probably get an answer in chat for those types of questions. I asked for more information in an attempt to help you bring this on-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it just asks us to confirm that a specific dictionary definition is correct and contextually relevant, with no indication as to why this might be "problematic".

Comment: @ColleenV How can I else ask then? If you think I lack the research, or dictionary-look-up, you vtc. Then so I dig into deeper the only way to remaing to confirm is the style like this. Look at this thread link [ https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/282910/regarding-a-metaphor-old-nick-is-not-just-lurking-in-the-small-print ], it was first closed due to the reason "Thsi question is off-topic. Answwers by dictionary look up is off topic". And it soon reopened. How would you native speakers want the OPs to ask?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, I don't know how deep we the OPs should do a research and how to confirm if I am right or not.

Comment: You've given no indication as to why you think that might *not* be the correct definition, so it seems to me this is a "Basic question ...[that]... should be answered using a dictionary" - specifically identified as the *first* "Off Topic" category in the site's Help pages.

Comment: If there’s a specific reason why you have doubts that’s the correct meaning, then someone could write more than a yes or no. As this question is written, it’s not on-topic. It’s not a bad question, it just doesn’t fit this site. It would be better to hop into chat and ask for a quick confirmation.

Comment: @ColleenV Hiow about this question [ https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/283059/seven-high-but-eight-high-another-meaning ] The first James' answer is "No, this is just a simple case of journalist who can't count." Essentially, he virtually said only No there isn't.

Comment: @ColleenV Then close kindly should the srtyle is off topic.

Comment: That answer doesn’t just say “No.” It has a lot of explanation of why it might have been written the way it was. The question includes a picture that helps us understand why “seven-high” wasn’t clear. If this question were similar, it would be on-topic. I know the close reasons sometimes aren’t very useful in understanding exactly why a question isn’t a good fit for the site.